# Blazor Cascading Parameter always 1 behind

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I am confused on what I am doing wrong here. In my layout file I have a header section that should change based on which page I am currently on. Here is the layout page.

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
<div class="min-h-full">
    <NavMenu/>


    <header class="bg-white shadow-sm">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-4 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <h1 class="text-lg leading-6 font-semibold text-gray-900">@PageTitle</h1>
        </div>
    </header>


    <main>
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="px-4 py-4 sm:px-0">
                @Body
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
</CascadingValue>

<Footer></Footer>
```

@PageTitle is the variable I am using to control the Header text.

Code Behind declares it as such.

```
public string PageTitle { get; set; }
```

Now on my view page I do this in the code behind.

```
[CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout? Layout { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Layout.PageTitle = "Current Page Header";
    }
```

Problem is it doesn't update properly, it will be blank the first page I go to, then when I click on a different page it will be 1 page behind in the header section. My guess is I am getting something confused with the state right now or I am doing this completely wrong.

Any help is so greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you might be only missing a StateHasChanged();

Comment: Where would I put that, I tried putting StateHasChanged() after each time I update the variable with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass the string value to the MainLayout and then call the StateHasChanged method to re-render it.

```
@code {
        private string _pageTitle ;

        public string PageTitle 
        {
            get => _pageTitle;

            set
            {
                if (_pageTitle != value)
                {
                    _pageTitle = value;
                }

                InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());

            }
        }

    }
```